# Approaches to P vs. NP in other fields of mathematics

Tags: soft-question, computational-complexity, computability

Often times it is useful for mathematicians to have multiple ways to approach a given problem. It is not uncommon to find solutions for a given problem making use of very different areas of mathematics.

I am particularly interested in other ways to formulate the P vs. NP problem. For instance, there are objects known as modular machines which are Turing-equivalent whose underlying mode of operation rely heavily on principles of number theory. I am wondering then, if there is a way to formulate the P vs. NP problem as a number theoretical one.

> More generally, are there equivalent problems to P vs. NP in other fields of mathematics? That is, can we reformulate P vs. NP in other mathematical disciplines?

I'm looking for something along the lines of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/331020/117710) answer on a question from CS.SE.

Comment: There is a related question here https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5855/18017 There are many compendiums available, with lists of (hundreds) NP complete problems from most domains in mathematics, including number theory. Start with the question above from stackexchange (or check the Wiki list). Since efficiently solving any of these problems would imply solving all of them ( polynomial time reducibility), you can look at any of these problems as a reformulation of P vs NP, in that particular field of mathematics.

Comment: @CristianDumitrescu: They'd still all be variants of "can such-and-such problem be decided in polynomial time using such-and-such computation model?" ... and therefore have a definite CS flavor. I think the OP here was hoping for something really different that doesn't look like it's about computatiton at all, such as P=NP iff the distribution of prime gaps has this-or-that asymptotic property. Or if such-and-such class of PDEs all have unique solutions.

Comment: Thank you @HenningMakholm  you are right. Well, you can encode a universal Turing machine into statements about Diophantine equations,  Chaitin's Diophantine equation computer  https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/24784   I don't know if,  how efficient this Turing machine is (halting time on a given set of starting states), can also be encoded in the language of Diophantine equations.

Comment: Yes, if you allow real RAM computability.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes that's exactly what I was getting at. I'm more interested in complete reformulations of P vs. NP in other mathematical disciplines. That said, the compendium of NP-complete problems mentioned by Cristian may point to potential avenues for reformulation, so I'll definitely give them a read.

Comment: @MoisheKohan can you please elaborate? Are you referring to what is discussed in [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~mbraverm/Papers/FOCS05.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwih2sXphpDjAhUOUt8KHZE0BTYQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2E-DQIihdIQYeH8awRym6c) paper?

Comment: What I have in mind is the work of Blum, Shub and Smale, as presented in their book "Complexity and real computation". According to them, working over complex (or real) numbers allows them to "take the NP out of the purely complexity-theoretic question P=NP and replace it by a simpler and more algebraic question..." about Hilbert's Nulstellensatz. See page 16 of their book. It also allows them to bring in some geometric methods.